# cover POS data formate to the one can apply Arules (Apriori)

Tags: r, apriori, arules

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3P6QR.png)Anyone can help with the suggestion how to covert the following data formate to the one 'Arules' can use. 
the dataset named 'df' is like

'Recieptnumber'      ,          'ProductName'
       1             ,              egg
       1             ,              apple
       2             ,              water
       3             ,             chips
       3             ,              apple
       3             ,             paper
.....

was using table(df) function to create matrix ---thoughts that is spares matrix . but it can not be used in 'Arules' package

any suggestion how to transfer the dataset?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use `read.transactions()` if you have it in a file or use the example from `? transactions`:

```
a_df3 <- data.frame(
   TID = c(1,1,2,2,2,3), 
   item=c("a","b","a","b","c", "b")
   )
 a_df3
 trans4 <- as(split(a_df3[,"item"], a_df3[,"TID"]), "transactions")
 trans4
 inspect(trans4)
```